# Is is possible to do an element attribute change as part of an animation chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to create a jQuery animation sequence where an image is swapped. I'm able to do what I want using callbacks, but not using a promise. Any suggestions?

Here's the example code showing a callback method that works, and a promise chain that doesn't.

```js
var img1 = "data:image/png;base64,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";

var img2 = "data:image/png;base64,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";

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    animation1();
});

function animation1(){
    var image1 = $("<img />", {
        css : {
            position   : 'absolute',
            left       : '0px',
            top        : '0px',
        },
        src : img1
    });
    
    $("#animationcontainer").append(image1);

    image1.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        image1.attr('src', img2);
        image1.fadeIn('slow');
    });
}

$('#button2').on('click', function() {
    animation2();
});

function animation2(){
    var image1 = $("<img />", {
        css : {
            position   : 'absolute',
            left       : '50px',
            top        : '0px',
        },
        src : img1
    });
    
    
    $("#animationcontainer").append(image1);

    return image1.animate({opacity: 0}, "slow")
               .attr("src", img2)
               .animate({opacity: 1}, "slow")
               .promise();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Animation 1</button>
<button id="button2">Animation 2</button>
<div id="animationcontainer" style="position:relative; width:500px; height:500px; background-color:grey"></div>
```

Comment: Do you really want to create fresh `<img>` elements every time a button is clicked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate() change text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939524/jquery-animate-change-text)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes, for separation of concerns the aim is to keep the animations separate from the rest of the DOM

Comment: @rdubya the answer you suggested does not use a promise, which is specifically what's been asked about

Comment: @user1379351 You're question asks how to change an attribute within an animation chain. If you view the answer I linked to, it shows you how to execute something within your chain. You don't need to deal with a promise to do it based on your example.

Comment: What is meant by "keep the animations separate from the rest of the DOM"?

Comment: I don't see where you are even trying to use the returned promise.

Comment: @rdubya if you look at my example, I'm also able to do what I want using callbacks, but I would like to do it using a promise, as that will fit better with the rest of my code.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 other than providing a container for the animation to occur in, the coders/designers making the page do not need to understand how the animation will work, or provide any DOM elements for it. The animation should be portable and work whatever the rest of the DOM on the page is. Hence "separate".

Comment: @charlietfl In this simple example I'm not using the promise. However, I want to be able to, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: Ok, my bad. When I tried the answer provided before it wasn't working, but it must've been a mistake on my behalf as I've tried it again and it works. Answer added below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant function using the suggested answer, modified slightly to incorporate a promise:

```
function animation2(){
    var image1 = $("<img />", {
        css : {
            position   : 'absolute',
            left       : '50px',
            top        : '0px',
        },
        src : img1
    });


    $("#animationcontainer").append(image1);

    return image1.animate({opacity: 0}, "slow")
                .queue(function() {
                    image1.attr("src", img2);
                    image1.dequeue(); // This is necessary to continue the animation
                })
               .animate({opacity: 1}, "slow")
               .promise();
}
```

Comment: user1379351, I don't want you to go away thinking that `.queue() ... .dequeue()` is necessary for generating a promise. Here's one of several ways to achieve the same end without using using `.queue()` - **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm0m28w0/)**. Personally, I find the need to `.dequeue()` counter-intuitive and use `.queue()` only when I am cornered into doing so, though I recall being very glad of it on one rare occasion a couple of years ago.