# Replacing button text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

Have a button I'm using with slideToggle to show divs. Button text is "Show Partial Client List"... when clicked it changes to "Hide Partial Client List". It works fine but I was wondering if I could add a transition effect so the text doesn't just abruptly change on click.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.show-clients').click(function() {
   $('.more').slideToggle(400);
   $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show Partial Client List' ? 'Hide Partial Client List' : 'Show Partial Client List');
   return false;
   });
});
```

The .more class is attached to the hidden div containing the content that will show when the button is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#/" class="button solid show-clients">Show Partial Client List</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery animate() change text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939524/jquery-animate-change-text)

Comment: You can, but to do so, you wont use the text() method to update it.

You will need to add a container to your button that contains the text, and fade that container in and out when ever the text changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but to do so, you wont use the text() method to update it. You will need to add a container to your button that contains the text, and fade that container in and out when ever the text changes.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#/" class="button solid show-clients"><div class="fadr">Show Partial Client List</div></a>
```

**JS**

```
  $('.fadr').fadeOut( 1000, function() {
     $('.fadr').html("Your New Text");
     $('.fadr').fadeIn();
  });
```

Comment: Nicely done. I got it to work using the click event and it still ties to the slideToggle. Thanks you so much. - Actually anyway to return the state to the original text?

Comment: Yes. See the solution below mine. He/she has included a ternary statement to switch between text on click.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` jQuery functions:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-clients').click(function() {
    //$('.more').slideToggle(400);

    $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show Partial Client List' ? 'Hide Partial Client List' : 'Show Partial Client List').fadeIn(200);
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/" class="button solid show-clients">Show Partial Client List</a>
```